# Getting Top X % based on total spend

Tags: marketing-cloud, automationstudio

What do you think is the best way to extract from a Marketing CLoud Data Extension the top 10 Percentage of customers based on total spend (CustTotalSpend). 
The bottom 15 percentage also based on total spend. 
and finally what is in the middle (remainder)  of both these segments. 
thanks.

My current query:

```
select top 20 percent SubscriberKey
, TotalSpend
, FirstName
, LastName
from Table1
where TotalSpend > 0
order by TotalSpend desc
```

Comment: The community is incentivised to help if you can provide attempts at you have made ... do you have any code you can post that indicated a good hearted attempt?

Comment: Here is some sample code of how far I got :                                          
select top 20 percent
SubscriberKey,
TotalSpend,
FirstName,
LastName
from Table1
where TotalSpend > 0
order by TotalSpend desc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is fairly simple.

1. You do `Top 10 Percent` with `Order by TotalSpend DESC` for the top 10% (similar to your example query) and aim this to a DE (Top10PercentDE).
2. You do `Top 15 Percent` with `Order by TotalSpend ASC` for the bottom 15% and aim this to a DE (Bottom15PercentDE).
3. You do a normal select statement with a `WHERE SubscriberKey NOT IN ( SELECT SubscriberKey FROM Top10PercentDE) AND SubscriberKey NOT IN ( SELECT SubscriberKey FROM Bottom15PercentDE`and aim it to a DE (RemainderDE).

This should provide 3 DEs that now contain the 3 categories you require.